# Android Flipbook Animation in Html5

Tags: android, jquery, html

i want to flip book animation effect in html5 or jquery with android supported.i want to animation effect in html page with supported android and i have tried lot of example's but doesn't work on android mobile phone page flip book animation effect like trun a page.any one can help me for working flip book animation html tutorial or code with supported android webview.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: this is not HTML but if you change your mind and you want to do the flipbook natively in Android: http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Comment: @JoséMi thanks but,i want to page curl effect in html!

Comment: That's why I added this as a comment and not as an answer :-) . Good luck anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial. I can't gaurantee it will work with all Android devices as the majority of Androids are pretty spartan.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/

Comment: Thanks for your answer flip book effect doesn't work in my android device!

Comment: well like I said most Androids are pretty spartan and can't really provide the support and horsepower needed to do most modern effects. This is one of the reasons why Android applications generally do not look as good as their iOS counterparts. The same goes for web. Most likely you are running Android 2.2/2.3 like everyone else on low end hardware. It just was not made to do things as well. I have a 2.3 device, it runs flipboard, but Idoubt the browser supports the 3D transforms it needs to do the web version. Check haz.io to see if yours does.